# How to remove 'loginError.data' is of type 'unknown' error?

Tags: typescript, next.js, antd, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am new to typescript and trying out `nextjs` and `rtk query` with `antd`.  By when trying to access `error` in `useLoginMutation` inside properties `error.data.message` , it shows `error.data` is type `unknown` .

What I have tried so far is I used a type guard function.

```
import { FetchBaseQueryError } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query";

export default function isFetchBaseQueryError(
    error: unknown
): error is FetchBaseQueryError {
    return typeof error === "object" && error != null && "status" in error;
}
```

```
if (!isLoginLoading && error) {
    if (isFetchBaseQueryError(error)) {
        notification.error({
            message: "Login Failed",
            description: error.data.message, // this line is causing error
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this one: https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-fire-hsjoqx?file=/src/App.tsx

```
import get from 'lodash/get'

function isFetchBaseQueryError(
  error: unknown
): error is FetchBaseQueryError & { data: { message: string } } {
  return (
    typeof error === "object" &&
    error != null &&
    "status" in error &&
    "data" in error &&
    !!get(error, "data.message") // make sure data.message exists
  );
}

const error = { data: { message: "message" }, status: "403" };
if (isFetchBaseQueryError(error)) {
  console.log(error.data.message);
}

const error1 = { status: "403" };
if (isFetchBaseQueryError(error1)) {
  console.log(error.data.message);
} else {
  console.log("data.message not defined");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it is still the same?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to import the new one. It works perfectly. Thanks, man.